# C - Pointers within struct not affecting the code

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to understand why this code works

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct identity {
    int age;
    char name[20];
} test;
int main(void) {
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", &test.name);
    printf("Enter age: ");
    scanf("%d", &test.age);
    printf("NAME: %s", test.name);
    printf("\nAGE: %d", test.age);
}
```

even if I define the struct this way:

```
struct identity {
        int *age;
        char *name[20];
    } test;
```

No matter how I write it, it works. I can understand that it works this way, but why does it work if I use the pointers?
I mean, shouldn't it require `printf("NAME: %s", *test.name);` and `printf("\nAGE: %d", *test.age);` so as to print the value held inside the address of `test.name` and `test.age` respectively?

Is this a wrong way to use pointers within a struct? Therefore it works because I actually don't use pointers?

Comment: You need to change `scanf("%s", &test.name);` to `scanf("%19s", test.name);` to prevent buffer overruns and also use the correct parameter

Comment: Please see [ask] and provide a [mcve]. There are no pointers in your code. An array is not a pointer!

Comment: @Olaf Ok, I edited the OP, I think it's more clear now.

Comment: @EdHeal Should I do this no matter if I use the pointers or not?

Comment: Please read the manual page for `scanf` to understand the parameters and its return value (this you should check)

Comment: As is looks, you seem to have not understood what pointers are, how `scanf` works and what to address-operator does. Why don't you read a C book? What have you done to solve these basic problems yourself? Asking about particular issues will not provide the overal understanding you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like many other questions, if you paid attention to compiler warnings, it'd be clear to you. When you change both struct members to pointers, you do get following compiler warnings:

```
str.c:11:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("NAME: %s", test.name);
     ^
str.c:12:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("\nAGE: %d", test.age);
```

What does those mean? So effectively you have changed it to 2D character array and a integer array (or int*). It still works because the starting address of them both remains the same still. So accessing a variable or a pointer just with starting address yields the same result. However, you do notice difference if you did something like,

```
test.age++
```

In case of `age` being an `int`, that increments the value by 1. In case `age` being an `int*` in increments the pointer to the next slot (sizeof(int) increment).

Comment: So it's actually correct if I use the pointers, or I misunderstood something?
In case I used `test.age++` with `age` being an `int*` I'd need to write it as such: `*test.age++` to increase its stored value, correct?

Comment: Depends on how you want to use it. If you want an array of strings and array of integers inside the struct, then you'd want to use pointers. The point is, it could "look" the same for a single entry case, but they are quite different from each other.

Answer (score 1):

Its because when you put `*` your `age` works as an array, and `char name[20]` works as 2D array. In C when you have some `array[]` or `array2d[][]` when you put somewhere `array` it is your first element `array[0]` and when you put `array2d` it is your first poem `(array[0][])`. You also can do `*(array+1)` and this is the same like `array[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

It occurs to me that an int will fit in the space of an int *, on today's computers, so you can put the int value in the address space of the int var, without corrupting the other values of the struct.  I added this to main():

```
 printf("\nsizeof int: %d", (int) sizeof(int));
  printf("\nsizeof int*: %d", (int) sizeof(int *));
```

and got this output on my system:
sizeof int: 4
sizeof int*: 8

Seems to me that's why it's working when the pointer vars are used instead of vars themselves?

Comment: Yes. But one should probably remember that using the wrong data types causes what the C standard calls undefined behavior, and the processor, the compiler and the runtime library may do all sorts of strange things, instead of what the programmer hoped for.